# R - Importing a Weird Messy CSV file

Tags: r, csv

I have searched through Stackoverflow and the web and found some similar solutions to what I would think would be a very simple problem but nothing that addresses this.  However, maybe I am just not thinking about it in correct "R" terms so here goes... Please help.

I have a few Odd CSV files which I have to process everyday.

Here is a mock up of the data as it comes in:

```
This is worthless and I want to get rid of it,,,,,,,,
This is worthless and I want to get rid of it,,,,,,,,
This line may or may not be here,,,,,,,,
This line may or may not be here,,,,,,,,
This line may or may not be here,,,,,,,,
Header1,Header2,Header3,Header4,Header5,Header6,Header12,Header13,
20345604,10.21.1151.12.0,Daisy,Petal,Stem,Data,Data,Data,
20345627,10.21.1151.12.0,Rose,Petal,Stem,Data,Data,Data,
20345600,10.21.1151.12.0,Samson,Petal,Stem,Data,Data,Data,
20345623,10.21.1151.12.0,Cloud,Petal,Stem,Data,Data,Data,
Header1,Header2,Header3,Header4,Header5,Header6,Header12,Header13,
20345704,10.21.1151.12.0,Simmons,Petal,Stem,Data,Data,Data,
20345677,10.21.1151.12.0,Butle,Petal,Stem,Data,Data,Data,
20347600,10.21.1151.12.0,Rose,Petal,Stem,Data,Data,Data,
20745623,10.21.1151.12.0,Unicorn,Petal,Stem,Data,Data,Data,
```

NOTES on the raw files:

- they are all standard csvs
- The number of columns may vary from file to file or day to day but the headers should always start with the same initial column name (in this example, "Header1").
- Each file will have at least 2-10 lines which are worthless and I don't need.
- The actual headers will appear within the first 10 rows
- All of the data after the first header row is part of Group1 and I want to add a new column "Group" with that as the data
- Eventually (5000 to 100,000 rows later), another set of the same header row will appear.  All of the data after this second header row is part of Group2 and I want to alter the data in the new Group column to match (i.e. - change to putting "Group2" in that column).

In the end I would like to end up with this (given the initial data above):

```
Header1,Header2,Header3,Header4,Header5,Header6,Header12,Header13,NEWFIELD
20345604,10.21.1151.12.0,Daisy,Petal,Stem,Data,Data,Data,Group1
20345627,10.21.1151.12.0,Rose,Petal,Stem,Data,Data,Data,Group1
20345600,10.21.1151.12.0,Samson,Petal,Stem,Data,Data,Data,Group1
20345623,10.21.1151.12.0,Cloud,Petal,Stem,Data,Data,Data,Group1
20345704,10.21.1151.12.0,Simmons,Petal,Stem,Data,Data,Data,Group2
20345677,10.21.1151.12.0,Butle,Petal,Stem,Data,Data,Data,Group2
20347600,10.21.1151.12.0,Rose,Petal,Stem,Data,Data,Data,Group2
20745623,10.21.1151.12.0,Unicorn,Petal,Stem,Data,Data,Data,Group2
```

I have tried to treat the data as a connection stream with a series of if/else statements to perform the identification of the headers, groups, adding the new columns, etc. but I am having issues putting it back into a form I can use with proper headers.

```
Group <- "Start"

  processFile = function(datafilepath) {
    con = file(datafilepath, "r")
    while ( TRUE ) {
      line = readLines(con, n = 1)
      if ( length(line) == 0 ) {
        print("EOF")
        break
      }

      if (grepl("Header1", line) & Group == "Start") {
          colnames(result) <- data.frame(paste(line,",","Group"))
          print("Initial Headers found, Switching to Group1")
          Group <- "Group1"
      } else if (grepl("Systems.Name", line) & Group == "Group1") {
          print("Switching to Group2")
          Group <- "Group2"  
      } else if (Group == "Start") {print("At Start")}

      if (Group != "Start") {
        indresult <- (paste(line,",", Group))
        result <- rbind(result, indresult)
      }
    }
    return(result)
    close(con)
  }
```

This code fails to load the headers correctly and I am not finding a method for loading the headers directly and then the data after that.  I am fairly certain the column additions should work if the other can be done but I can't get to the point of verifying the resulting data will be seen as a complete dataframe until I can get past this.

**Main Questions:** Is this the correct method to go about this and, if so, how do I get the data into a data frame to be able to be able to use it?

Thanks,

---

**Solution I am using currently**: 
The earlier solution with fread was the closest but I had a hard time wrapping my brain around it and the := assignment operator isn't recognized on my setup. 
Thus, here is what I eventually used:

```
#This line removes all rows before the appears of "Header1"
Data <- fread(paste(Folder, File, sep = ""), skip="Header1")
    Group= "Group1"

    #Add additional column to data frame to be filled in below
    Data$Group= ""

    #Loop through each row and add Group - I had tried using simply "Data" instead of 1:nrow(Data) but in that case R only took the initial column of Data and not each row itself.  
    for (dataline in 1:nrow(Data)) {
      if (Data[dataline,]$"Header1" == "Header1" & Group == "Group1") {
        #Reached second row of Headers indicating Group change
        Group <- "Group2"
         next
      }
        #Assign Group 
        Data[dataline,]$Group <- Group

    }
  #Remove Duplicate Header rows
  Data <- Data[!(Data$Header == "Header1"),]
```

---

It is slow (takes about 4-5 minutes to run through on 50,000 rows) but it at least is automatic and gets what I need.  If there is a way of speeding it up, please feel free to add.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you open to non R solutions? While this could be done in R, it would be way more efficient to clean the file and create the new column with a different tool like `awk`, `pyhhon` or `perl`. R works best when you feed it clean and regular data files.

Comment: Currently I am using another scripting language to do this part now (Powershell).  It works but it wasn't designed for that, it takes a while, and there isn't a way of automatically loading the results to the other R scripts I need to actually get the answers I need (i.e. - the scripts which will take this data once cleaned).

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
x = 'This is worthless and I want to get rid of it,,,,,,,,
This is worthless and I want to get rid of it,,,,,,,,
This line may or may not be here,,,,,,,,
This line may or may not be here,,,,,,,,
This line may or may not be here,,,,,,,,
Header1,Header2,Header3,Header4,Header5,Header6,Header12,Header13,
20345604,10.21.1151.12.0,Daisy,Petal,Stem,Data,Data,Data,
20345627,10.21.1151.12.0,Rose,Petal,Stem,Data,Data,Data,
20345600,10.21.1151.12.0,Samson,Petal,Stem,Data,Data,Data,
20345623,10.21.1151.12.0,Cloud,Petal,Stem,Data,Data,Data,
Header1,Header2,Header3,Header4,Header5,Header6,Header12,Header13,
20345704,10.21.1151.12.0,Simmons,Petal,Stem,Data,Data,Data,
20345677,10.21.1151.12.0,Butle,Petal,Stem,Data,Data,Data,
20347600,10.21.1151.12.0,Rose,Petal,Stem,Data,Data,Data,
20745623,10.21.1151.12.0,Unicorn,Petal,Stem,Data,Data,Data,'


require(data.table)
require(zoo) # for na.locf

o = fread(x, skip = 5,sep= ',')

# count how many headers
nh = nrow(o[grepl('Header1', V1) & grepl('Header2', V2)])

# add header id 
o[grepl('Header1', V1) & grepl('Header2', V2), group := 1:nh]

# fill down header
o[, group := na.locf(group, na.rm = FALSE)]

# remove rows containing 'Header*'
o = o[!grepl('Header1', V1) & !grepl('Header2', V2) ]

o

         V1              V2      V3    V4   V5   V6   V7   V8 V9 group
1: 20345604 10.21.1151.12.0   Daisy Petal Stem Data Data Data NA     1
2: 20345627 10.21.1151.12.0    Rose Petal Stem Data Data Data NA     1
3: 20345600 10.21.1151.12.0  Samson Petal Stem Data Data Data NA     1
4: 20345623 10.21.1151.12.0   Cloud Petal Stem Data Data Data NA     1
5: 20345704 10.21.1151.12.0 Simmons Petal Stem Data Data Data NA     2
6: 20345677 10.21.1151.12.0   Butle Petal Stem Data Data Data NA     2
7: 20347600 10.21.1151.12.0    Rose Petal Stem Data Data Data NA     2
8: 20745623 10.21.1151.12.0 Unicorn Petal Stem Data Data Data NA     2
```

`x` should be the path to your csv file.

Also, check out `data.table::fread` for more arguments that might be useful here.

You could further use `setnames()` to change the column names and perhaps change data types from character to numeric in case the original dataset has it.

Comment: I changed the example to accommodate the group column.

Comment: I think I will end up using something a bit different but that seems to get me much closer.  The hint about the fread function solves one issue--> the fread option "skip=" can take a text value to search for before it starts grabbing the header labels (which takes care of the first issue with all of those files I don't want before the column labels).  Your using skip=5 works but the number of lines will vary and I won't know ahead of time and I am trying to remove all manual tasks.

Comment: then probably I would use the following scheme: 1) read all lines . 2) use regular expressions (e.g. grepl() to find all garbage lines. 3) optionally change data types from char to numeric